# What encoding does the PowerShell switch statement use when -File is used?

Tags: powershell

What encoding does the PowerShell switch statement use when -File is used? It's basically reading from a file, so I would have expected some control over the encoding applied to the bytes read?

What I mean is not Get-Content etc., but the switch statement, e.g.:

```
switch -File ~\Desktop\demo.md -Regex
{
    '^$'
    {
        'Blank line'
    }

    '^#\s(.*)$'
    {
        'Heading'
    }

    '^-(.*)$'
    {
        'Bulleted list'
    }

    default
    {
        'Normal line'
    }
}
```

Converting bytes read to interpreted characters, by definition, uses a certain encoding, right?

Comment: Can you be more specific? Which cmdlet? Get-childItem uses `-File` but it does not read file content. Get-Content read those file and uses ASCII as the default. Are you seeing behavior that contradicts that? Can you show some examples and pehaps the ps version you are using.

Comment: Since get-content can read many formats, I propose it does some sort of auto figuring it out. Or at least .net does. And I'm guessing he probably has a file giving the wrong format... Maybe starting the file with basic characters and then not including that line in the input could fix this maybe? Like `get-content file.txt | where {$_ -ne "text of first line"}`

Answer (score 1):

The -file option in the switch is rarely used but does give speed and memory usage advantages. As far as I can tell the exact encoding is currently undocumented.

The example we use on page 171 of PowerShell in Action 3rd edition uses Out-File to create the file we'll use in the switch statement. Out-File defaults to Unicode so I'm going to **ASSUME** that switch -file also uses Unicode.

If you need to control the encoding, or the file doesn't appear to read correctly then revert to using Get-Content.

I repeat that my assumption of Unicode is based on the PowerShell help system information rather than any explicit knowledge.

Comment: Reread your - much appreciated - response just now. It looks like you're right, but I hesitate to mark yours as the definitive answer since it's based, as you wrote, on an assumption. I'll continue to search for concrete evidence that you're right ;-), and will report back here should I find something.